# Is there a way to center a card in a container using Materialize CSS?

Tags: html, css, materialize, card

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<body class="grey darken-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- I have tried adding center, center-align as a class to div tags but it in correctly formats. My form elements to the center which was not what I except -->
      <div class="col s12 m6 l10">
        <!-- adding center, center- align to the row still doesn't fix the issues still -->
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title center ">Loan Calculator</span>
            <form action="">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-field">
                  <span>$</span>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount">

                </div>

                <div class="input-field">
                  <span>%</span>
                  <input type="number" class="ïnput-field" placeholder="Loan" class="form-control">

                </div>

                <div class="input-field">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Years To Pay">
                </div>

                <div class="center">
                  <input type="submit" value="CALCULATE" class="btn black">
                </div>
                <h5 class="text-darken-3 center " id="result">Results</h5>


              </div>


            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I don't know if this is a current issue with Materialize CSS itself.

My goal is to properly format the card so that it has 6 columns for medium display. However, the card, when resized to small width, behaves in a erratic manner (the content is aligned to the left, and the space on the right is left empty).

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the "issue" (I would say it is by-design) is the combination of `float: left;` and `margin-left: auto;` with no `margin-right: auto;` rules applied for columns with `.col.m*` classes. Because of this, columns are always snapped to the left of the containing row.

If you want to override this to center your column, you need to specify an *offset*. What Materialize CSS [Grid](https://materializecss.github.io/materialize/grid.html) (implemented with `float`) expects you to do is to express that the column taking ½ of the containing row width should be *offset* by 6 divided by 2 columns on both sides (aka "centered").

Offsets in Materialize CSS are provided with the `offset-*` set of classes. In your case, you only need the `offset-m*` and `offset-l*` subsets. Let's take a look:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<body class="grey darken-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- I have tried adding center, center-align as a class to div tags but it in correctly formats. My form elements to the center which was not what I except -->
      <div class="col s12 m6 l10 offset-m3 offset-l2">
        <!-- adding center, center- align to the row still doesn't fix the issues still -->
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title center ">Loan Calculator</span>
            <form action="">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-field">
                  <span>$</span>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount">

                </div>

                <div class="input-field">
                  <span>%</span>
                  <input type="number" class="ïnput-field" placeholder="Loan" class="form-control">

                </div>

                <div class="input-field">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Years To Pay">
                </div>

                <div class="center">
                  <input type="submit" value="CALCULATE" class="btn black">
                </div>
                <h5 class="text-darken-3 center " id="result">Results</h5>


              </div>


            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it does work but what I don't understand is that the offset-l2 shifts the content by two columns to the right of the already left-centetered div. Without also affecting the left?

Comment: @geek oh, it's pretty simple: `offset-*` classes add `margin-left` of a certain percentage. Since Materialize's grid is not really a Grid but an old `flex` implementation, they simply push the floated column to the right.